# aiboビジュアルプログラミングで、aiboの持ち上げ→移動に適切なコマンドは？

Tags: aibo-developer, aibo-visual-programming

aiboビジュアルプログラミングについて、実行前だとaiboが動き回ります。
指示待ちを実行しても、持ち上げて移動させると、伏せの姿勢になってしまいます。

ワンワントレインやワンワンウェーブのように、実行後（緑の旗マーク等）、
一定時間や●●を撫でるまで「立った状態で待ち、持ち上げて移動させても伏せの姿勢にならない」ようにする
適切なコマンドはありますでしょうか？

感覚的には
「●●するまで」の中に「止まる」や「XX秒待つ」だとは思うのですが、
公式として、確実に立ったまま脱力せずに移動させる、コマンドブロックの組み合わせがあれば教えてください。

Comment: https://aibo.sony.jp/fan/visual_programming/ にある "Q : 「指示待ち中になる」「指示待ち中から復帰する」ブロックとは何ですか？" の項目とはまた違うものなんでしょうか

Comment: ＞shingo.nakanishiさん
aiboは気分屋ですから、興味のあるものや声がする方向を向いたり、遊んだり、休んだりします。

「指示待ち」「指示待ち解除」は、ビジュアルプログラミングからの指示（天の声）に従うように、魂を抜くような【おまじない】【催眠術】のようなものです。

指示待ちをしないと、途中で遊んでしまったり、やめてしまうことがあります。

逆に指示待ちにした後、指示待ち解除をしないと、タイムアウトまで、ずっと魂が抜かれた、催眠術にかかったままになってしまいますので注意してくださいね。

Comment: なるほど。失礼しました。

Answer (score 0):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

> 「立った状態で待ち、持ち上げて移動させても伏せの姿勢にならない」

これを実現するためのブロックはありません。
また、aibo Web API にもこのような API はありません。

指示待ち中であっても持ち上げられると aibo は抱っこ状態になり、
予期せぬ動きを防ぐために API の実行を受け付けなくなります。
床に置かれてしばらくすると、aibo は再び API の実行を受け付けるようになります。

**参考：https://aibo.sony.jp/fan/visual_programming/#faq30**

> Q : 「動作を実行できませんでした」というエラーがでます。 A : aibo を抱き上げているときや、aibo
> が脱力状態になっているときは API をうまく実行できません。しばらく待っても復帰しない場合は aibo を再起動してください。

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム